# The Intern: Checking for Elements that Shouldn't Exist

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, intern

I'm writing a functional test for a custom Dropdown Control we've built that has "readonly" functionality.  The original test plan we came up with for this was to make sure the "list" wasn't being drawn when clicking on the dropdown, which is what would happen normally.  The markup for the list doesn't exist in the DOM until it's drawn.

The functional test looks like this:

```
'can respond to clicks while in read-only mode, but will not open the menu': function() {
    return this.remote
      .get(require.toUrl('/tests/dropdown/readonly'))
      .setFindTimeout(10)
      // Click the dropdown pseudo element
      .findById('readonly-dropdown-shdo')
        .click()
        .end()
      // attempt to find the dropdown list (should not exist because this is a "readonly" dropdown)
      .findById('dropdown-list')
        .then(function(element) {
          expect(element).to.be.empty;
        })
        .end()
      // Check the currently active element (should be the psuedo-element)
      .getActiveElement()
        .getAttribute('id')
        .then(function(id) {
          expect(id).to.equal('readonly-dropdown-shdo');
        })
        .end();
},
```

The test fails at `.findById('dropdown-list')` because Selenium is throwing a "NoSuchElement" exception, which is true because the element doesn't exist.  The problem is that Intern's test runner automatically fails tests that get these errors, as far as I can tell, even though this behavior is expected.

My question:  Is there a preferred way to expect that an element should not exist on the page at a particular time?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`findDisplayedById()`](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#findDisplayedById) instead of `findById()` like this:

```
.findDisplayedById('dropdown-list')
        .then(...)
        .catch(...)
        .end()
```

Comment: No such luck.  _findDisplayedById()_ still tries to find the DOM element physically on the page, and in this case it doesn't exist.

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. - try `.catch()` after the `findDisplayedById()` since it is a promise.

Answer (score -3):

Don't check for what shouldn't be there, check for what SHOULD be there, ie: your pseudo-element.

(FWIW, were I you I would just disable the dropdown instead of swapping around elements. This would make it easier to test and is still semantically correct. Dropdowns do not expand when disabled.)